# How to run the Python program in the background in Ubuntu server

Tags: python, selenium, server, ubuntu-16.04, nohup

I have a python script. Script have selenium with Chrome and go to a website, take data and put in CSV file.
This is a very long work.
I put the script on the server. And run. All work.
But I need script work in the background.

```
chmod +x createdb.py
nohup python ./createdb.py &
```

And I see

```
(env)$ nohup ./createdb.py &
[1] 32257
(env)$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

Press Enter.

```
(env)$ nohup ./createdb.py &
[1] 32257
(env)$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
[1]+  Exit 1                  nohup ./createdb.py
```

Then it runs and immediately writes errors to the file, that Chrome did not start or there was no click.
I want to remind you that if you start without nohup, then everything will work.
What am I doing wrong? How to run a script?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the screen command, it works perfectly.

Here is a very good link: https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Comment: Is it like tmux?

Comment: I think it is better to redirect you to the following stack exchange discussion https://superuser.com/questions/236158/tmux-vs-screen
Please mark your question as answered if you have found what you looked for

Answer (score 3):

You could create a background daemon (service)
You taged Ubuntu 16.04 it means you got systemd, for more information on how to set it up, please visit this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files)

create a file called `<my_service>.system`
and put it there:  `/etc/systemd/system`

you systemd unit could look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=my service
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/my_dir
ExecStart=python my_script.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then all you have to do is, reload systemd manage and start your service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl myservice start
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Urban48. But it seemed to me very difficult.
can you show an example of a simple python script that you need to run in a virtual environment?
Or maybe you know a book where it is described for beginners?

Comment: @asergey, its not hard at all. i outlined exactly what you need to do in my answer, just few easy steps. take the time to read a little about it, or watch a video.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a simple command, from the env directory:

```
(env)$ python /path/to/createdb.py > logger.txt 2>&1 &
```

This will help for storing the program logs in a defined file called "logger.txt"

Comment: Without screen or tmux or nohup, your background process will be killed whenever the terminal or shell is closed or you exit the ssh session.